# Different line length in horizontal legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to create an horizontal legend with several lines (with different lengths) and the text below each line. I have the following code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

colorlevel <- brewer.pal(n = 5, name = 'Set1')

plot.new()
a <- legend("topleft",
            legend =c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
            lty = 1,
            lwd = 4,
            bty='o',
            seg.len= c(rep(1.5,5), 4),
            col = colorlevel,
            horiz = TRUE,
            trace=TRUE
)
text(a$text$x-0.05, a$text$y, c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), pos=1)
```

which produces the following legend:

[Horizontal legend with different line lengths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHKBr.png)

However, there are some problems that I am not able to address:

1. The last line (the largest, corresponding to F) must maintain the same separation as all other lines, but it is quite separated.
2. Although I want the distance between the colored lines to be the same, is there a way to adjust this separation?
3. The border of the legend is too close to the text, etc. Can it be adjusted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

colorlevel <- brewer.pal(n = 5, name = 'Set1')

plot.new()
a <- legend("topleft",
            legend =c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
            lty = 1,
            lwd = 3,
            bty='o',
            seg.len= rep(1.5,5),
            col = colorlevel,
            horiz = TRUE,
            trace=TRUE,
            cex = 1.3
)
#you can experiment more with "cex" parameter in legend and text for more accurate output
text(a$text$x-0.06, a$text$y, c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), pos=1)
```

[image]

Comment: The parameter seg.len cannot be changed because I need the F line larger than the others. The problem is that it is drawn far away from the other lines and all lines must maintain equal separation between them.

Comment: @dreamco9 Do you think, that is real to do?

Comment: I wanna put the legend below a plot to separate different regions in the X axis, giving a name to each one

Comment: @dreamco9 You can do it. But I don't know how to save different length of legend's elements and same spaces between them in the one moment. Maybe, it is real to do, but I'm not sure...